# Should build folders be included in a git repo?

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, gulp

I'm trying to set up a git repository for my bespoke WordPress theme builds, using gulp to compile the code but im struggling to understand how to manage the repo.

**The outcome I'm after:**

1. Use a separate repo to pull in my gulp workflow. (Could be housed as a submodule)
2. Offer developers full access to my gulp workflow, src and build.
3. Push the build folder to remote servers such as production and staging.

**Current Scenario**

My gulp workflow will be held in a separate repo as it will be used amongst several different builds.

The current workflow I can think of would look like this:

```
gulp-wp-build -> git repo

src -> git repo

build -> WordPress ready theme not held in a repo
```

Ideally though I'd like to be able to push my code to the production and staging servers through git and I understand that to do this I'd need to do include the build folder inside of my repo. *But would including both my src folder and build folder within the repo be overkill?*

I like the idea of containing everything inside of one repo so other developers can work on the theme later down the line using either their gulp workflow or the one I used for the build.

But really in terms of pushing changes through git I'd only want the build to be pushed live so could I separate this build folder from the repo when pushed to a certain remote?

Answer (score -2):

Use a .gitignore file to do that.

create a .gitignore file and inside put the path or the files that will be ignored by git.

```
relative/Path/to/your/autogenerated/files/*
```

after you finish, commit and push your file to your remote repository

check this [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: I understand how this would help to stop the autogenerated build files from appearing in the repo but wouldn't this prevent me from pushing those files alone to a remote?

I think if I could only do one of the two I'd prefer to be able to push the build directory to a remote and have to include it in my repo.

Comment: first you have to tell git "don't track these files", but, if you already uploaded those files to the remote repo, you have to to this ... 

1st. Erase the autogenerated files, commit and push.
2nd Create the .gitignore file and set the path to the autogenerated folder.
3rd Commit and push the .gitignore file.

Now your autogenerated files are not tracked anymore by git.

Comment: I think @Scolie is asking "why" or "should I" and not "how".